# Passing additional parameters to the Zend partialLoop View Helper

Tags: php, zend-framework

In a Zend view I can apply a partial template to an iterable element as follows:

```
$this->partialLoop('template.phtml', $iterable);
```

However inside the template, only the elements of the $iterable are available, is there another way of passing extra data to the partial?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use

```
$this->partialLoop('template.phtml', array(
    'data' => $iterable, 
    'otherVariable' => $otherVariable
);
```

### Warning & Edit:

To be completly honest, I made a mistake. I guess that the code I proposed won't work. I mistaken it for the partial() helper. It won't work because of this part of the helper's class:

```
foreach ($model as $item) {
    // increment the counter variable
    $this->partialCounter++;
    $content .= $this->partial($name, $module, $item);
}
```

It will iterate over the whole array instead of the "data" key. I don't get how the answer could be accepted :D Thanks to **Nikolaus Dulgeridis** for pointing that out.

You can't even post any extra data through $this->view because the point of partial is that it creates "clean" view instance - so that the assigned variables won't collide with your existing variables.

### Possible options

#### - Extend the view helper with methods to set custom variables

#### - Iterate the array and reformat it to

```
array(
    array('data' => $item1, 'id' => 1, 'totalCount' => 10) ,
    array('data' => $item2, 'id' => 2, 'totalCount' => 10) ,
    array('data' => $item3, 'id' => 3, 'totalCount' => 10) ,
)
```

#### - Use Registry to store the values.

```
Zend_Registry::set('partialLoopCount', $count);
$this->partialLoop($viewScript, $data);
```

#### - Dump partialLoop and use partial() instead

I prefer this solution.

```
$count = count($data);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo $this->partial($viewScript, array('item' => $value, 'position' => $key, 'count' => $count));
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Inside the partial, you can access all of your view variables with:

```
$this->partialLoop()->view->myVariable
```

where myVariable is a normal view variable (`$this->view->myVariable` in the controller or 
`$this->myVariable` in the view, which it's actually the same thing).
Basically, you retrieve the PartialLoop() object, then the view which called it, and then the variable itself.

This, though, will probably impact performance (and I don't think it's really MVC friendly...)
But, hey: it works. :)

An example here:
[Hardcode.nl == Joris Osterhaus](http://www.hardcode.nl/archives_132/article_511-access-view-values-from-partialloop.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Later I found (insert in partial):

```
$this->getHelper('PartialLoop')->view->otherVariable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access parent view variables by this way :

```
$this->ViewModel()->getCurrent()->getVariable('parentVariable');
```

Found at http://blog.dossantos.com.au/how-to-access-parent-view-variables-from-a-partial-loop-in-zf2

Answer (score 0):

In controller

```
$this->view->otherVariable = 'otherVariable';
```

In "partial file" - template.phtml

```
$this->otherVariable
```

(ZendFramework-1.11.4-minimal)